# Associate DIM table with duplicate values to FACT

Tags: ssis, ssas, row-number

I have a DIM (dim.ReceiptType) with 2 columns:
ReceiptID and ReceiptType
ReceiptType has 2 values: 1 or 0, therefore ReceiptID repeats at least 2 times in a column.
The same columns exist in a FACT table with the same # of values.

Is there an elegant way to connect ReceiptType from DIM to ReceiptType in FACT in SSIS or SSAS?
I've been thinking of this solution: If the 2 tables have the same columns and # of values, maybe I'll assign a ROW_NUMBER as a connecting KEY.
Is it a good solution? Is so, please assist on how to do it properly.

Comment: Have you tried using Slowly Changing Dimension Transform to load dimension tables. Also a fact table is a series of surrogate key lookups. Your lookup will have a series of Lookup Transforms, where you pass in the alternate key and return the surrogate key Use a Lookup Transform against  dimension tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we're facing a design issue here. There are essentially two ways you could approach this situation:

1.
All dimensions in a data warehouse should have "surrogate" (artificial) keys so that you can avoid situations like this, i.e. when you get duplicates of natural keys (those that came with facts) with different sets of attributes.

Surrogate keys usually work like this: upon receiving fact data, you isolate various combinations of dimensional attributes (in this case `ReceiptID` and `ReceiptType` pair) and put those into a table with an `IDENTITY` column. Once this is done, you do a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) or a `JOIN` (depending on whether you're working via an *ETL* layer or in *SQL* directly) to match the values from the facts to particular dimension members you just added.

This is explained in more depth by one of the [data warehousing gurus here](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1998/05/02/surrogate-keys/). If you're not a Kimball fan, you can look the concept of "surrogate keys" anywhere on the interwebs.

2.
(and somewhat expanding on the above)
It may be that the values you're trying to move into a dedicated dimension are of granularity similar to that of the facts, i.e. you will often have one ReceiptID matching exactly one fact row. In such circumstances there's not much benefit in creating a dedicated dimension, you might want to separate ReceiptType only, leaving ReceiptID in the fact table as a [degenerate dimension](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/06/03/design-tip-46-another-look-at-degenerate-dimensions/) or moving it out of the fact table with other unrelated attributes as a [junk dimension](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/03/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/). Also, *SSAS* has [native support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5457b857-23b9-4398-829c-a2e0c75dbc1d/how-to-add-a-degenerate-dimension-in-ssas-2008?forum=sqlanalysisservices) for degenerate dimensions so you'd have the option to avoid significant change to you ETL logic.

Comment: IDENTITY column is the best solution for me, since the Fact and Dim table use common source.